# Method names for event handlers S100

Tags: c#, sonarqube

The Sonar rule csharpsquid:S100 (Method name should comply with a naming convention) is thrown also for event handlers that are generated by Visual Studio, something like:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DoIt();
}
```

Is it possible to ignore this rule for event handlers as they are auto-generated?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We have already changed the default Regex for this rule to allow underscores. The next version of the C# plugin will use that. Until then you can change the Regex yourself to `^[A-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*[a-zA-Z0-9]$`.

Comment: Where do we need to change the Regex?

Comment: You can change the parameter value through your quality profile. The same place where you activate or deactivate a rule.

Comment: We added this info to the documentation pages: http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Configuring+Rules